# The color of the first swipe of SwipeRefreshLayout is always black, only changes color after the swipe is released

Tags: android

This is my code for SwipeRefreshLayout. My app primary color is Green, and i want my SwipeRefreshLayout progress is same with primary color. But, the first swipe is always Black color.

```
XML

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_explore_buyer_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    ...

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

```
Kotlin

swipeExploreBuyerRefresh.apply {
    setOnRefreshListener {
        setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeResource(R.color.white)
        
        setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.primary,
            R.color.orange,
            R.color.red
        )

        shimmerExploreBuyerItemOutlet.apply {
            startShimmer()
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
       
        showOutletList()
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the colors inside the refresh listener, move ‘setColorSchemeResources’ outside the listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and it will work according to your requirements. If you want to show the loading only in one color then you can pass only one color in setColorScemeResources

```
swipeExploreBuyerRefresh.apply {
        setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.primary,
            R.color.orange,
            R.color.red
        )
    }
```